# Pandas count the number of times an event has occurred in last n days by group

Tags: python, pandas

I have table of events occurring by id. How would I count the number of times in the last n days that each event type has occurred prior to the current row?

For example with a list of events like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'event_day': '2016-01-01', 'event_type': 'type1'},
{'id': 1, 'event_day': '2016-01-02', 'event_type': 'type1'},
{'id': 2, 'event_day': '2016-02-01', 'event_type': 'type2'},
{'id': 2, 'event_day': '2016-02-15', 'event_type': 'type3'},
{'id': 3, 'event_day': '2016-01-06', 'event_type': 'type3'},
{'id': 3, 'event_day': '2016-03-11', 'event_type': 'type3'},])
df['event_day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event_day'])
df = df.sort_values(['id', 'event_day'])
```

or:

```
   event_day event_type  id
0 2016-01-01      type1   1
1 2016-01-02      type1   1
2 2016-02-01      type2   2
3 2016-02-15      type3   2
4 2016-01-06      type3   3
5 2016-03-11      type3   3
```

by `id` I want to count the number of times each `event_type` has occurred prior to the current row in the last n days. For example, in row 3 id=2, so how many times up to (but not including) that point in the event history have events types 1, 2, and 3 occurred in the last n days for id 2?

The desired output would look something like below:

```
    event_day   event_type  event_type1_in_last_30days  event_type2_in_last_30days  event_type3_in_last_30days  id
0   2016-01-01  type1       0                           0                           0                           1
1   2016-01-02  type1       1                           0                           0                           1
2   2016-02-01  type2       0                           0                           0                           2
3   2016-02-15  type3       0                           1                           0                           2
4   2016-01-06  type3       0                           0                           0                           3
5   2016-03-11  type3       0                           0                           0                           3
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last row of your expected output have all zeros for the event counts in the last 30 days?  The second to last row is the only other row for id 3, and the `event_day` values are more than 30 days apart.

Comment: @root you're right. Updated.

Comment: Both approaches are nice and worked. I tested on a larger dataset with around 10k rows and ayhan's approach was around 5x as fast (3s vs 15s), but both were workable. One thing that i failed to show in my example was the event_day wasn't unique so the merge wasn't quite working juanpa.arrivillaga, but i just concatenated the two dfs and it worked fine. Also, both matched one another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
res = ((((df['event_day'].values >= df['event_day'].values[:, None] - pd.to_timedelta('30 days')) 
        & (df['event_day'].values < df['event_day'].values[:, None]))
        & (df['id'].values == df['id'].values[:, None]))
        .dot(pd.get_dummies(df['event_type'])))
res
Out: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

---

The first part is to generate a matrix as follows:

```
(df['event_day'].values >= df['event_day'].values[:, None] - pd.to_timedelta('30 days'))
Out: 
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

It's a 6x6 matrix and for each row it makes a comparison against the other rows. It makes use of NumPy's broadcasting for pairwise comparision (`.values[:, None]` adds another axis). To make it complete, we need to check if this row occurs sooner than the other row as well:

```
(((df['event_day'].values >= df['event_day'].values[:, None] - pd.to_timedelta('30 days')) 
   & (df['event_day'].values < df['event_day'].values[:, None])))
Out: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Another condition is about the id's. Using a similar approach, you can construct a pairwise comparison matrix that shows when id's match:

```
(df['id'].values == df['id'].values[:, None])
Out: 
array([[ True,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

It becomes:

```
(((df['event_day'].values >= df['event_day'].values[:, None] - pd.to_timedelta('30 days')) 
    & (df['event_day'].values < df['event_day'].values[:, None]))
    & (df['id'].values == df['id'].values[:, None]))
Out: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Lastly, you want to see it for each type so you can use get_dummies:

```
pd.get_dummies(df['event_type'])
Out: 
   type1  type2  type3
0    1.0    0.0    0.0
1    1.0    0.0    0.0
2    0.0    1.0    0.0
3    0.0    0.0    1.0
4    0.0    0.0    1.0
5    0.0    0.0    1.0
```

If you multiply the resulting matrix with this one, it should give you the number of rows satisfying that condition for each type. You can pass the resulting array to a DataFrame constructor and concat:

```
pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(res, columns = ['e1', 'e2', 'e3'])], axis=1)
Out: 
   event_day event_type  id   e1   e2   e3
0 2016-01-01      type1   1  0.0  0.0  0.0
1 2016-01-02      type1   1  1.0  0.0  0.0
2 2016-02-01      type2   2  0.0  0.0  0.0
3 2016-02-15      type3   2  0.0  1.0  0.0
4 2016-01-06      type3   3  0.0  0.0  0.0
5 2016-03-11      type3   3  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I really enjoyed ayhan's approach. But I have another which is probably slower (just my assumption that `apply` is usually slow), although I think the logic is more straightforward. If anyone wants to try to compare the two, especially how they scale, I'd be very interested:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd, numpy as np

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'event_day': '2016-01-01', 'event_type': 'type1'},
{'id': 1, 'event_day': '2016-01-02', 'event_type': 'type1'},
{'id': 2, 'event_day': '2016-02-01', 'event_type': 'type2'},
{'id': 2, 'event_day': '2016-02-15', 'event_type': 'type3'},
{'id': 3, 'event_day': '2016-01-06', 'event_type': 'type3'},
{'id': 3, 'event_day': '2016-03-11', 'event_type': 'type3'},])

In [3]: df['event_day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event_day'])

In [4]: df = df.sort_values(['id', 'event_day'])

In [5]: dummies = pd.get_dummies(df)

In [6]: dummies.set_index('event_day', inplace=True)

In [7]: dummies
Out[7]: 
            id  event_type_type1  event_type_type2  event_type_type3
event_day                                                           
2016-01-01   1               1.0               0.0               0.0
2016-01-02   1               1.0               0.0               0.0
2016-02-01   2               0.0               1.0               0.0
2016-02-15   2               0.0               0.0               1.0
2016-01-06   3               0.0               0.0               1.0
2016-03-11   3               0.0               0.0               1.0

In [8]: import datetime

In [9]: delta30 = datetime.timedelta(days=30)

In [10]: delta1 = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

In [11]: dummies.apply(lambda x: dummies[dummies.id == x.id].loc[x.name - delta30:x.name - delta1].sum() ,axis=1)
Out[11]: 
             id  event_type_type1  event_type_type2  event_type_type3
event_day                                                            
2016-01-01  0.0               0.0               0.0               0.0
2016-01-02  1.0               1.0               0.0               0.0
2016-02-01  0.0               0.0               0.0               0.0
2016-02-15  2.0               0.0               1.0               0.0
2016-01-06  0.0               0.0               0.0               0.0
2016-03-11  0.0               0.0               0.0               0.0
```

Finally, you can `merge` `dummies` and your original dataframe after dropping the 'id' column in `dummies`:

```
In [12]: dummies.drop('id', inplace = True,axis=1)

In [13]: dummies
Out[13]: 
   event_day  event_type_type1  event_type_type2  event_type_type3
0 2016-01-01               0.0               0.0               0.0
1 2016-01-02               1.0               0.0               0.0
2 2016-02-01               0.0               0.0               0.0
3 2016-02-15               0.0               1.0               0.0
4 2016-01-06               0.0               0.0               0.0
5 2016-03-11               0.0               0.0               0.0

In [14]: pd.merge(df, dummies, on="event_day")
Out[14]: 
   event_day event_type  id  event_type_type1  event_type_type2  \
0 2016-01-01      type1   1               0.0               0.0   
1 2016-01-02      type1   1               1.0               0.0   
2 2016-02-01      type2   2               0.0               0.0   
3 2016-02-15      type3   2               0.0               1.0   
4 2016-01-06      type3   3               0.0               0.0   
5 2016-03-11      type3   3               0.0               0.0   

   event_type_type3  
0               0.0  
1               0.0  
2               0.0  
3               0.0  
4               0.0  
5               0.0
```

Comment: Yes, it got out of hand really quickly :) Would be nice to test them on another sample. I'm still not sure if mine is working correctly.

Comment: @ayhan Yeah, I was hitting my head against the wall trying to achieve this using resampling and cumulative sums. Pretty much ended up going with a "functional brute-force" approach.